# Rotation of custom cell in uitableview hides data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am working on my application with uitableviews using custom cells.
I first rotate my table view in `viewdidload` as:

```
self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
```

to make it horizontal. It works fine. 
Now I need the custom cell to rotate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

The contents of the custom cell (image, two labels) disappears in some cases.

Can you explain why?

Comment: What are the cases that it disappears?

Comment: for CGAffineTranformMakeRotation(M_PI_2) it disappears when i comment the cell.transform line it appears, and also when its value is else from M_PI_2

Comment: Could it be that the problem appears when a cell is reused?

Comment: can  you   show  as cellforRowatIndexPath method implementation?

Comment: did it @Andrew , i answered to my question, check to the reason below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a number of tricks, atlast found that there was some overlapping of cells problem, you have to set rows of tableview in a way so that they doesn't overlap.